# Yii Binding values for In Query

Tags: php, yii

Currently I am Using this query

```
$presentRecords=  Yii::app()->db
->createCommand()
->select('productId')
->from('exhibitorproducts')
->where(array('and',"exhibitorId=$exhibitorIdentity",
array('in','productId',$productRecords)))
->queryColumn();
```

But the problem with this query is that I am using **$exhibitorIdentity**  and **$productRecords** directly. I think that it is dangerous. **So how can i bind these values?**

Answer (score 2):

Try this...
for more http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder

```
$presentRecords=  Yii::app()->db
->createCommand()
->select('productId')
->from('exhibitorproducts')
->where("exhibitorId=:exhibitorId AND productId IN (:productId)", array(':exhibitorId'=>$exhibitorIdentity, ':productId' => $productRecords))
->queryColumn();
```

EDIT to

```
 $presentRecords=  Yii::app()->db
    ->createCommand()
    ->select('productId')
    ->from('exhibitorproducts')
    ->where(array("and","exhibitorId=:exhibitorId", array("in", "productId", ":productId")), array(':exhibitorId'=>$exhibitorIdentity, ':productId' => $productRecords))
    ->queryColumn();
```

Comment: I tried it but its giving the false result. for **IN (2,3)** its returning result for only **2** and if i remove 2 from the query then its showing result for 3 :(

Comment: $productRecords is an array(2,3) and so It throws error **Array to string conversion** for **$productRecords**.